# ipython parallel management tool for cluster/engines/tasks

Tags: parallel-processing, ipython

How can I manage an iPython parallel cluster?

I've successfully created a cluster with about 35 engines running on several machines with varying hardware/os. After a few days executing several tasks I would like to be able to view the state of my cluster. More specifically I would like to know:

Which engines are (still) running and on what machines?
What resources did/do those engines consume (memory/cpu) on the hosts?
Which tasks are currently executing/have executed on which engine and what was the result/status of those tasks (success/failure)?

Preferably I would like to use some kind of (web-based) user interface to answer those questions.